# View / Edit tabs no longer functional

Tags: 7

I seem to have done something to mess up the View / Edit tabs which appear above page content when you are logged in with appropriate rights. The tabs appear but they are no longer clickable. If I access the "edit" link via the dashboard, I can edit the page contents no problems - it's just the handy short-cut that has stopped working.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you use Jquery Update Module?

Comment: You can check that you haven't absolute positioned a transparent element over the links.

Comment: Yes, I have Jquery Update installed and enabled. It's there in support of Open Layers which I am not using right now so I could remove this module if it causes problems.

Comment: Is this Drupal 7 or 8?  If this is 7, are you using the Overlay?  Right away I agree with Patrick Ryan, that is sounds like there is some invisible element overlapping the tabs.  You can check this by inspecting the source code using something like Firebug or Chrome's Dev Tools.

Comment: I think you are right - there is some invisible/transparent element in the way. I have not yet discovered what it is, but I know that if I change the theme from the one I am using (Corolla) to another (Bartik) the tabs become again active. I think I must have changed a setting for Corolla (there are a lot of them).

Comment: OK, I have not worked out what the invisible element is, but I know how I slipped my content under it. Unhappy with too much vertical whitespace between the page header and the main content I added a quick-and-dirty bit of css to the page.css file : margin-bottom -40px as a property of the header-wrapper. This gave me the appearance I wanted but clearly slid the main content under another element. I need to study the page.css file in a bit more detail to get the layout I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome/firefox's inspector and click on the edit link that will highlight the element that's sitting over the top of it and you can sort your CSS out for that element